# set SKNode position in spriteKit

Tags: swift

how works constraints in spriteKit? I have a global var

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

then, i am trying to add my sknode.

```
personage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bro")
        personage.position.y = CGFloat(-screenSize.height)
        personage.position.x = CGFloat(-screenSize.width)
        personage.size = CGSize(width: screenSize.width/3, height: screenSize.height/3)
        addChild(personage)
```

It is perfect on small size iphone, but when i open 13 pro max i cant see my personage, whats wrong? How do i change my code to see the same sizes of personage on all devices[image]

Comment: can you add a background color to your Bro node to make its actual dimensions visible? It doesn't look like it's 1/3 screen width. Afaik SK coordinates have 0 in the center which makes all your calculations place the object off screen.

Comment: everything ok with bro, i already checked it